# Proxy Details with SFTP command

Tags: sftp

I'm trying to login into the sftp server but its giving me this

```
Connecting to sftp.ABCD.com...
/bin/sh: line 1: exec: connect: not found
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

These are the credentials that I'm trying to give

The credentials for the sftp server is below:

SFTP servers information:

Proxy Address:   proxy.ABCD.com
Host name:       sftp.ABCD.com
Port:            32
User Name:       wakao
Password:        123!@#

I tried with several combinations but I couldn't arrive at a conclusion as in where and why its giving me the above mentioned message

```
sftp -o "ProxyCommand  connect -S proxy.ABCD.com:80"   wakao@sftp.ABCD.com:32
sftp -o "ProxyCommand  connect -S proxy.ABCD.com:80    %h    %p"  wakao@sftp.ABCD.com:32
```

Where am I going wrong? Or how to specify the command properly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the shell on the SFTP server cannot find the command `connect`. Two likely causes:

1. Your `$PATH` is not set. Try replacing `connect` with `/usr/bin/connect` or `$(which connect)`. Or login with SSH and locate this program.
2. The SFTP server does not have `connect` installed. Contact the system administrator of the machine.

Comment: Which package needs to be installed for the connect commad to be available ? Also, is this 'connect' not found error for my local machine or the sftp server ? Where exactly we need to install connect (client machine on which command is fired or sftp server) ?

Answer (score 6):

As Schot said I contacted the System Administrator & after installing the connect the command is:

```
sftp -o "ProxyCommand connect -H proxy.ABCD.com:80 %h %p" wakao@sftp.ABCD.com
```

Comment: CreateProcessW failed error:2
posix_spawnp: No such file or directory
i got this error. Windows OS

Answer (score 6):

In RHEL/CentOS 7 clients and Linux versions where the `nc` command doesn't recognize the `-x` and `-X` command-line arguments (e.g. `Ncat: Version 7.50`), the working command would be:

```
sftp  -o ConnectTimeout=3 -o ProxyCommand='/usr/bin/nc --proxy-type http --proxy proxy.ABCD.com:80 %h %p' -oPort=32 wakao@sftp.ABCD.com
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following command (Cygwin) for connecting to SFTP servers over SOCKS proxy:

```
sftp -oProxyCommand='nc -v -x<proxy address>:<port> %h %p' userid@host
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, on Fedora 19, with the following .ssh/config file:

```
# Outside of the firewall, with HTTPS proxy
Host myhost.hostname.org
ProxyCommand corkscrew proxy 80 %h 443 ~/.ssh/auth.txt
# Inside the firewall (do not use proxy)
Host *
ProxyCommand connect %h %p
```

I solved just replacing the line

```
ProxyCommand connect %h %p
```

with:

```
ProxyCommand connect-proxy %h %p
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not looks like there is any .rpm or .deb package that provides /usr/bin/connect - as few answers refer on this page. This has worked for me on Fedora - provided nmap-ncat rpm is installed.

```
sftp -oProxyCommand='/usr/bin/nc -v -x myproxy.mycompany.com:9999 %h %p' -oPort=6789 sftpUser@sftp.remote.server.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to add to the comments above, if you don't happen to have a friendly SA that will install connect for you, and you have a compiler on your machine, it's dead simple to build connect:

1. Get the source code from http://www.pontusvision.com/?attachment_id=1316
2. Compile the code with the following command line:

`gcc connect.c -o connect  -lresolv  -lsocket   -lnsl`

and then add the newly compiled connect executable to a directory in your path...

and if you have the @ symbol in your user name, you can run the following:

`sftp -o "ProxyCommand  connect -H proxyuser@proxy.ABCD.com:80 %h %p " -o "User  your_remote_sftp_user@email.com"  sftp.ABCD.com:32`

Comment: I've added it on my company's site for now: http://www.pontusvision.com/?attachment_id=1316