# How to transfer the files from one server to another server SFTP using nc Proxy Command

Tags: command, line

I have used the below command line to connect the SFTP server using proxy command but I am trying to send mulitple/single file and it is not working.

sftp  -o ConnectTimeout=3 -o ProxyCommand='/****/bin/nc --proxy-type http --proxy ********:8888 %h %p' -oPort=22 username@servername:/directories

I want to know how to send the file/files with above command

Transfer single/multiple files from one server to another server. Once above line works here.

Answer (score 0):

sftp -o ConnectTimeout=3 -o ProxyCommand='/****/bin/nc --proxy-type http --proxy ********:8888 %h %p' -oPort=22 username@servername:/directories - **Tell to connect the sftp server with nc proxy command.** Reference Link - [Proxy Details with SFTP command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334123/proxy-details-with-sftp-command)

Now, I want to transfer the file from Linux server to AWS SFTP. We need to use backticks.
**`**- It is used to whatever the commands inside the backticks, it will read/execute the command and place the result.

file = How to give the filepath with backticks mentioned in the image - Reference Link - [UNIX evaluate expression from a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411082/unix-evaluate-expression-from-a-variable)

[image]

**$file** - Whatever the output comes from **`(Backticks)** command and it will place on the substitution command.

**sftp -o ConnectTimeout=3 -o ProxyCommand='/****/bin/nc --proxy-type http --proxy proxy.xyz.com:8888 %h %p' -oPort=22 username@servername:/directories <<< "put $file"** - It is worked.